# Is CouchDB proxy authentication implemented in IBM Cloudant?

Tags: authentication, couchdb, reverse-proxy, cloudant, api-key

As stated by [Apache CouchDB documentation](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/server/authn.html#proxy-authentication):

> Proxy authentication is very useful in case your application already uses some external authentication service and you don’t want to duplicate users and their roles in CouchDB.

Hence a reverse proxy can authenticate a user and send the username (as `X-Auth-CouchDB-UserName` HTTP header) along with a token (as `X-Auth-CouchDB-Token`) generated from this username and a general shared secret (not related with this particular user).

As stated:

> This authentication method allows creation of a User Context Object for remotely authenticated user.

This user context can be useful in a `validate_doc_update` function (for authorizations) or in an `update` function (for accounting).

Among third party CouchDB hosts, IBM cloudant is one of the most famous. However the product is slightly different, especially concerning security (see [matrix](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Cloudant?topic=Cloudant-couchdb-and-cloudant)).

Whereas I am familiar with proxy authentication in Apache CouchDB, I didn't manage to setup a similar feature in Cloudant nor to find documentation about it. In particular, IBM "API keys" (composed by a key and a password) don't seem to be compatible with setting a different username as `X-Auth-CouchDB-UserName`.

Does anyone succeeded in setting up (in Cloudant) a user context different from the credentials used for authentication? Or is there a doc anywhere saying that it is not possible?

Answer (score 1):

@robert-newson confirms that:

> Cloudant does not enable the proxy authentication handler nor supports
> externalising authentication/authorization decisions in any other way.
> Use either IBM IAM or the CouchDB _users database within your account
> (note that the _users database option is not available for Transaction
> Engine instances).

Comment: @robert-newson  I would like to credit you for the correct answer. If you want too, please copy your own answer and will accept it.